# ParentRecordType field on ServiceAppointment

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I have this code and I was trying to get the ParentRecordType field in System Debug but I got strange issue. As you can see by getSObjectType I can check if parent record type equals WorkOrder but when I try to get field value itself I get null [image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please do not post code (or error text, or other important text) as screenshots - it is not as accessible to users who use screen readers or other assistive technology. Plus it makes it harder for anyone to help if they want to copy your code and put it in a sandbox or code editor. Instead, copy your code and paste it in the SFSE editor with three backticks (```) above and below it in order to format it as a code block. Please [edit] your question to add the code as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to test the SObjectType of an Id field is:

```
if (ss.ParentRecordTypeId.getSobjectType() == WorkOrder.SObjectType) {..}
```

No need to resort to `getDescribe()`.

Answer (score 0):

This will be because the value of that field won't have been set before it is inserted into the database. At this point in the execution, the ParentRecordId will be set as this is part of the ServiceAppointment record itself, but the evaluation of what type of object that parent record is won't have occurred.

Rather than using the ParentRecordType field, you'll have to get the SObject Type as you've done in the last debug statement.